# Does Salesforce Single Sign on stop all access with a Password?

Tags: single-sign-on, custom-domain

Pretty silly question - sorry.  If a user is set up with Salesforce Single Sign On can they still log in with a password if they don't have domain access?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Administrators can choose if this is allowed or not, as defined in the *My Domain* setup. Note that the domain password and Salesforce password may differ; they will need to know their Salesforce password to log in if this is allowed.

Comment: Thanks.  We are still on test and as I understand it when we deploy the domain we will be able to (by default unselected) choose whether or not the setting "prevent login from login.salesforce.com.." is checked. 
 See https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_domain_name_sso.htm&type=0